# Declare and assign a variable in if statement condition, reuse in statement body

Tags: c#

I can't really phrase the question's title. Anyway, say I have a statement like:

```
if(myObject.SomeMethod() != null)
{
    DoSomethingWith(myObject.SomeMethod());
}
```

I'd like to avoid a double call to `SomeMethod()`. Ideally, something à la pattern matching like:

```
if(myObject.SomeMethod() result != null)
{
    DoSomethingWith(result);
}
```

Is there something in the language that can help me with this? At the moment, my choice is to go with:

```
var result = myObject.SomeMethod();
if(result != null)
{
    DoSomethingWith(result);
}
```

I know there's nothing wrong in the method above, it's very canonical. Simply put, a lot of syntactic sugar has been added to the language lately, allowing us to condense our code a lot: I'm asking because I don't know if there's something preventing `if(myObject.SomeMethod() result != null)` to work.

Comment: What's bad with using a variable? That's exactly what you should do

Comment: I would suggest explaining what you find wrong, perhaps you have a false assumption

Comment: Absolutely nothing intrinsically bad, like nothing was bad in `var x = y as T; if(x != null) { }` instead of `if(y is T x) { }`

Comment: Being able to do this would be even more useful when the condition is part of a while loop rather than an if statement. Otherwise you have to assign the variable before the loop, and re-assign (ie update it) within the loop. Having a one-liner means you can combine those into a single assignment in the condition which makes it a lot cleaner and easier to read. (coming from a background in Python, I wanted to reach for the 'walrus operator')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, i'd suggest to use a variable as you did in your third code. However...

You can use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) if you don't want to use a variable:

```
if(myObject.SomeMethod() is var result && result != null)
{
    DoSomethingWith(result);
}
```

But note that this doesn't prevent access to the variable `result`. You can even access it after the `if`. If you want that you need a new scope: `{ if... }`.

Comment: If you know the type `T` returned by `SomeMethod`, can you condense to `if (myObject.SomeMethod() is T result)` ? (I.e. does that include the null check?)

Comment: @Rawling: i don't think that this compiles

Comment: Understood. Seems to work but as you suggested, but it's less readable. Thank you for your suggestion.